# Although ByteBuf is not guaranteed to be thread-safe, will this use case be OK?

Tags: netty

(I know that the [`ByteBuf` documentation does not say anything about thread safety](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html).)

I have a `ByteBuf` that I wish to share between two threads in a very, very specific way.

I have control over the code executed in both threads for this one use case.

Specifically, **thread one**, which is the event loop, **will be reading from the `ByteBuf` in sequential order.  It will never write**, nor will it call any method other than [`readRetainedSlice`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html#readRetainedSlice-int-), [`isReadable`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html#isReadable--), [`asReadOnly`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html#asReadOnly--) and [`readableBytes()`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html#readableBytes--).

**Thread two, which is not the event loop, will be appending bytes** to the `ByteBuf` using its [`writeBytes`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html#writeBytes-byte:A-int-int-) method.  It will call no other method on `ByteBuf`.

No other method will be called on this `ByteBuf`.

[`ByteBuf` itself is an abstract class with no fields](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/buffer/src/main/java/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.java) and no documentation related to threads so obviously there can be no *guarantee* that any given implementation of it will be thread safe with this usage pattern.

But *practically* speaking, are all Netty `ByteBuf` implementations descended from [`AbstractByteBuf`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/AbstractByteBuf.html), which would seem to be thread safe at least in this particular use case?  Or must I arrange the writes to my `ByteBuf` to happen on the event loop as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your use case involves **only** the sequential access semantics of `ByteBuf` exposed (among others) by its `readRetainedSlice` and `writeBytes` methods, you're guaranteeing its *readable bytes area* and its *writable bytes area* won't overlap, hence, no multithreading access conflict hazard will occur. The use of `isReadable`, `asReadOnly` and `readableBytes` have no effect on thread safety **for your specific use case** but will add an extra layer of safety.